# Python : how to remove data from set from another set

Tags: python, list, set

I have one reference list, such as :

```
dico = [ 'test', 'blabla' ]
```

And I would like to remove these items that are contains in an other list :

```
listTest = [ 'S01_test', 'S02_ahah', 'S03_blabla' ]
```

The result should be :

```
[ 'S02_ahah' ]
```

I try to use sets, but with no success. Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in listTest if x.split('_')[1] not in dico]
['S02_ahah']
```

Or with [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> dico = [ 'test', 'blabla' ]
>>> listTest = [ 'S01_test', 'S02_ahah', 'S03_blabla' ]
>>> filter(lambda x: x.split('_')[1] not in dico, listTest)
['S02_ahah']
```

If you are on `python-3.x` remember to wrap [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#filter) with `list()` since it returns an iterator:

```
>>> f = filter(lambda x: x.split('_')[1] not in dico, listTest)
>>> list(f)
['S02_ahah']
```

I would have probably prefer the use of `filter()` with a `lambda` over the list comprhension, but from a very basic timing the comprehension seems to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension

```
bad_stubs = [ 'test', 'blabla' ]
input = [ 'S01_test', 'S02_ahah', 'S03_blabla' ]

#Gets an item from a list, if not there gives None
def lget(list, index, default=None):
    return list[index] if len(list) > index else default

results = [i for i in input if lget(i.split('_'), 1) not in bad_stubs]
```

A generator could also be used:

```
results = (i for i in input if lget(i.split('_'), 1) not in bad_stubs)
```

Note: the `i.split('_')[1]`style will error if there is no stub (item after the _)